# Why were the trackers necessary in Catching Fire?

Tags: the-hunger-games

So

> All the tributes in Catching Fire were drawn from earlier victors.

Why did they need to have another tracker implanted? Did the trackers go bad?

Comment: I don’t think this is addressed in canon, but perhaps it gets removed in the post-game medical check-up? Nobody knew the Victors were returning to the Games until the 75th Games were announced, so there wouldn’t be a reason to leave them in.

Answer (score 2):

The trackers are a way of the Gamemakers to know where each player is, and to know when they die; I imagine the trackers send off a signal when each tribute dies so that the Gamemakers can enter the arena and collect the body. 
The old trackers were likely removed or otherwise deactivated after the victors left their arenas. The new trackers they were given were probably designed specifically for the current arena, so their old trackers - assuming they could still have worked - would not be accurate in showing the placement of each tribute.

Comment: Can you find any references in canon for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of *Catching Fire* Katniss finds out that President Snow is aware of her illegal forays into the woods. She considers several possible methods via which he could have known this, but does not consider the tracker from the Hunger Games. Moreover, shortly thereafter she plans on fleeing District 12 along with a few others, yet never once considers the possibility that the Capitol would be able to easily find her via the Hunger Games tracker.

This would imply that it is taken for granted that the trackers either don't work after the Games end, or are specifically removed after the Games end. In either case the victors  participating in the Quarter Quell would need new trackers.